# Symfony SoftDeleteable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have entity and I use

```
* @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
```

and when I delete some entity in my database I have my entity and in field deletedAt I have time when I delete entity and this is ok. But Now I need find all deleteAt entity? I create QB

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');
$qb
    ->select('d')
    ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Project', 'd')
    ->where('d.deletedAt IS NOT NULL');

$count = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
$query = $qb->getQuery();
$results = $query->getResult();
return [$results, $count];
```

I have 0 entity, why and how find entity ?

**UPDATE**
In my controller

```
class ProjectController extends FOSRestController
{
public function getProjectsAction(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
{
$manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        if($paramFetcher->get('status'))
    {
        $manager->getFilters()->disable('soft-deleteable');
        $queryBuilder = $manager->getRepository('ArtelProfileBundle:Project')->findForStatusProject($paramFetcher, $this->getUser());
    }
```

and I have error

```
 Filter 'soft-deleteable' is not enabled.
```

my entity

```
/**
 * Project
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="project")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Artel\ProfileBundle\Entity\Repository\ProjectRepository")
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Project
{
/////
/**
 * @var \DateTime $deletedAt
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 * @Type("DateTime")
 * @Expose()
 */
protected $deletedAt;
```

help please

Comment: You need to disable the filter using `$entityManager->getFilters()->disable('soft-deleteable')` like it says in the docs - https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/softdeleteable.md#setup-and-autoloading . Otherwise it will never find them due to them being "deleted".

Comment: where I need disable filter in entity repository I can?

Comment: Before you create the query.

Comment: have error, I update

Answer (score 5):

Solved
 it is simply a mismatch between the name I use in my config and in my code

```
        filters:
        softdeleteable:
            class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
            enabled: true
stof_doctrine_extensions:
default_locale: "%locale%"
orm:
    default:
        timestampable: true
        sluggable:     true
        softdeleteable: true
```

and then in my action I do

```
$manager->getFilters()->disable('softdeleteable');
```

And have the entity which I deleted

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, debugging the FilterColletion Class I found a simpler solution

$manager->getFilters()->disable('soft_deleteable'); //(using dash instead of minus sing, the last one is parsed to a dash )